# Set up a sharded solr collection using solrcloud

Tags: solr4, solrcloud

I would like to set up a 6 shards solr collection on 3 windows machines.

Tried the bin\solr -e cloud and set up 2 machines 6 shards and 1 replica. When stopping and starting 2 cores on one machine (each using another hard disk) I get 6 shards; 3 for each core.

When I start another core on another machine nothing happens, the 3rd one doesn't do anything.

When I start another core on the same machine using the same config in another directory nothing happens, the core starts but has no collections and the 2 cores first started still have 3 shards each.

For example: I start the 3rd one with:

```
bin\solr start -c -p 7576 -z localhost:9983 -s server/solr/collection/node3/solr
```

Or start on another machine:

```
bin\solr start -c -p 7576 -z zookeeper:9983 -s server/solr/collection/node3/solr
```

Is there some documentation out there that doesn't use the "convenient" bin\solr that I'm trying to reverse engineer the entire day to figure out how to set up zookeeper/solr to add the nth solr core as a shard until 6 shards are reached?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer: `bin\solr -e cloud` starts up the cores and assignes data to them.

After running the standard `bin\solr -e cloud` with 2 cores, a collection with 6 shards and 1 replica I stop all `bin\solr stop -all`

Then copy `solr-5.2.1\example\cloud\node1` as `solr-5.2.1\example\cloud\node3` delete the files in `solr-5.2.1\example\cloud\node3\logs` and let `solr-5.2.1\example\cloud\node3` have `gettingstarted_shard6_replica1` (leave that file in `solr-5.2.1\example\cloud\node3\solr` and remove it from `solr-5.2.1\example\cloud\node1\solr`).

Start up 3 cores:

```
bin\solr start -c -p 8983 -s example\cloud\node1\solr
bin\solr start -cloud -p 7574 -z localhost:9983 -s example\cloud\node2\solr
bin\solr start -cloud -p 7575 -z localhost:9983 -s example\cloud\node3\solr
```

And now I can see the 3rd solr instance has gettingstarted_shard6_replica1